# Javascript reverse a list of numbers using closure

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reverse a list of numbers however I am getting an output of `undefined`.

I am using closure to do it 
here is my code

```
function reverseANumber(aList) {

    function reverse() {
        var newList = [];
        var j=0;
        for(var i = aList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            newList[j] = aList[i];
            j++;
        }
        return newList
    }
    reverse(aList);
}

aList=[3,2,3,1];
console.log(reverseANumber(aList));
```

I am getting `undefined` as output
I am expecting `1 3 2 3` as output

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: You are not returning anything from `reverseANumber`, thus `undefined` is *implicitly* returned. You need `return reverse(aList);`. Though I don't understand why you need the inner function.

Comment: Why don't you just use `Array.prototype.reverse()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: plus one, why not [.reverse](http://jsfiddle.net/b23wt4a1/)?

Comment: @GergoErdosi because I did not know it exist. Love JavaScript. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel :)
Use [Reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reverse)

```
var aList=[3,2,3,1];
aList.reverse();
console.log(aList)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 3, 2, 3]
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/aOoLoB)

Answer (score 3):

Simple

```
function reverseMe (list){
 return list.reverse();
};

reverseMe([1,3,2,3]); // returns 3,2,3,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a return statement before the reverse(aList) call:

```
function reverseANumber(aList) {
    function reverse() {
        var newList = [];
        var j = 0;
        for(var i = aList.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            newList[j] = aList[i];
            j++;
        }
        return newList;
    }
    return reverse(aList);
}

aList = [3,2,3,1];
console.log(reverseANumber(aList));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just declared a function inside of a function, which won't work.
Try this:

```
function reverseANumber(aList) {
    var newList = [];
    var j=0;
    for(var i = aList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        newList[j] = aList[i];
        j++;
    }
    return newList;
}
reverse(aList);
}
aList=[3,2,3,1];
console.log(reverseANumber(aList));
```

Comment: I am trying to use closure, that is why I declared a function inside of another

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverseANumber(aList) {

  let lastIndex = aList.length - 1;
  let result = [];

  function reverse(aList, lastIndex) {
    if (lastIndex === -1) {
      return;
    }
    result.push(aList[lastIndex])
    reverse(aList, lastIndex - 1);
  }

  reverse(aList, lastIndex);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: A 'good answer' also includes a sentence or two in plain text that explains why you think your solution will work. Please visit SO Help Center and specifically this guideline for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer